# ConnectionError: (7, "couldn't connect to host")

Tags: python, python-2.7

I parse the following webstie: http://zakupki.gov.ru/
Two weeks ago everything was fine with 3500 requests but now it crashes after about 500 and give me the above-mentioned ConnectionError. Then I switch the connection from one wi-fi connection to other and the code works again until the same Error appears. Then I switch to 3g and it works again, but the same Error repeats. I tried to change DNS to Google's but it doesn't help. What problem might it be?
Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Probably they block your IP after a number of connections for denial of service protection.